# Вставить картинку в jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Есть папка images на диске C.
Как вставить картинку в  jsp из этой папки ?

Пробую так:

```
<img src="C:/images/1.jpg"/>
```

Но ничего не получается.
Прошу помощи , объясните , пожалуйста, как это сделать?

У меня есть форма , через которую пользователь загружает картинку. Картинка загружается по адресу `C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.18/webapps/ROOTuploads/`.

В БД есть таблица user , в которой есть поле `photoPath` - в нём хранится путь к картинке .

То есть , я никак не могу получить картинку с БД при использовании пути?

**Обновление**

У меня есть сервлет , в котором загружаются картинки :

```
     String applicationPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
    // constructs path of the directory to save uploaded file
    String uploadFilePath = applicationPath+UPLOAD_DIR;
    File fileSaveDir = new File(uploadFilePath);
    if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
        fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
    }
    System.out.println("Upload File Directory="+fileSaveDir.getAbsolutePath());

    String fileName = null;
    //Get all the parts from request and write it to the file on server
    for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
        fileName = getFileName(part);
        part.write(uploadFilePath + File.separator + fileName);
    }


    request.getSession().setAttribute("fileName", fileName);
    System.out.println("In servlet:"+fileName);
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/student/userProfile").forward(
            request, response);
```

Сейчас картинки грузятся в C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.18\webapps\ROOTuploads , то есть , на диск .

Я так понял, что их нужно грузить в какую-то папку самого приложения.

Как это сделать? Нужно в WEB-INF создать папку?

Comment: тоесть вы полагаете что браузер пользователя имеет доступ к диску сервера?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо указывать не путь на диске, а относительный путь в проекте.

Например:
`<img src="/MyApp/WebContent/images/logo.jpg" />`

Если файлы необходимо подгружать конкретно с жесткого диска, то нужно понимать, Нужно понимать, что для браузера загрузка изображения-это загрузка с конкретного URL адреса из тега `<img>`. Для этого необходимо реализовывать сервлет, который будет эти изображения отдавать.
Ссылка должна указывать адрес сервлета, который отдает изображения. Можно добавить параметры, по которым будет определяться какое именно изображение отдавать.

```
<img src="imageServlet?param1=value1" />
```

Сервлет получает параметры, определяет необходимый файл, читает его и отдает в `response.getOutputStream()`

```
@WebServlet("/imageServlet")
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       // Create image based on request.getParameter() information.
       // Set proper content type by response.setContentType().
       // Write image to response.getOutputStream().
   }
```

}

Comment: А если у меня на диске хранятся в отдельной папке? Во время работы приложения туда загружаются картинки и эту папку я не могу поменять. Что тогда делать?

Answer (score 0):

У меня была похожая проблема мне помогло когда я прописал маппинг сервлета в web.xml 
сдесь я указал всю папку.

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern> <!--Путь к папке-->
 </servlet-mapping>
```

отдельные фото можно сделать :

```
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```